# Nested href in a form

Tags: php

I have a script that I downloaded and want to add an href="#" to it but it's interfering with the form on the page. The form is triggered by a button, not sure of that matters. I tested my href outside the form but it still refreshes the page once before it works. Here is the code.

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile/save_profile_setting">


<a href="#" class="locate_me" id="locateMe">Update My Location</a>


</form>

<button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" ><span><?php echo __( 'Save' );?></span></button>
```

My href just passes the id to run ajax to find a location, it's always worked but now the two aren't playing well together. I have the same href on a different page by itself and it works fine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please explain what this is suppose to do. It's very unclear since just wrapping a form around `<a>`-tag makes no sense and then have a submit button outside of the form? What's the purpose of the form? What are you expecting the submit button to submit? How are they related? What is it that refreshes the page? The button? The link?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what is your actual query. I understood roughly of your query. My understanding for your question is that: with  tag, you want to execute ajax call and with button, you want to perform form action. Based on this assumption:

(1) If you want to avoid page refresh with  tag, you need to do as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="locate_me" id="locateMe">Update My Location</a>
```

Now, you can easily perform ajax with  tag.

(2) To perform button action with form, you need to add button inside form instead of outside the form.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it properly. I have a script I downloaded that has a profile page that obvious;y has a form that save the info, it's saved with a button and I think ajax. I added this link <a href="#" class="locate_me" id="locateMe">Update My Location</a> that works when on a page by itself but it refreshes that page when on the same page with the form.

Comment: If you are performing saving of profile info with button with ajax, then no problem, you can do. And for refreshing issue of `<a>`, you can pass `javascript:;` in href attribute to stop refreshing of page.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not explaining it properly. I have a page with a form on it. I added an anchor link to the page href="#" and the page refreshes once, then I have to refresh the page again for it to work. I don't want the page to refresh, just run my javascripr. I think the achor is try to submit the other form on the page